# Delphi RIO Android Application interface freeze

Tags: android, delphi

I have developed a delphi rio android application.
I have a button to make "some syncronization" bettwen a datasnap server application and the local database.
In order to update the interface I have moved the code into a TTask interface and update the main UI with Thread.Synchronize.

```
procedure TdmMain.Syncronize;
begin
  taskSyncro := TTask.Create(
    procedure()
    begin
      SignalUpdateUI('...Syncro Start...');
      // ....... loats of code here
      // connecting to datasnap
      SignalUpdateUI('...Step 1...');
      // insert into local database
      // etc...
      SignalUpdateUI('...Syncro End...');
    end);
  taskSyncro.Start;
end;

procedure TdmMain.SignalUpdateUI(baseMessage: String);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
    begin
      // write into memo
      memoLog.Add(baseMessage);
    end
  );
end;
```

sometimes the code is working ok but sometime is freezing in the "middle" of the procedure.
can anyone point me why the app is freezing? or any useful information to figure out what to fix?
i have explain only the basic but all the ui updates are made with SignalUpdateUI.

Razvan

Comment: Use `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread` instead of `TTask.Create`. I am speaking form experience here. None of my Android apps have `TTask` anymore.

Comment: I suspect the problem is happening in the parts you have left out

Comment: tks nolaspeaker. After switch to CreateAnonymousThread i have no problem (after some testing). Also the UpdateUI i changed to "TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread," instead of nil.